# Database schema for variable number of columns

Tags: sql, database-schema

So I have an app that takes any type of data file (csv,tsv, etc), but that data can vary - it can be sports, weather, or even genomics data, thus the columns will be different.

One schema I think of is having one table for each specific file format. When loading a new file in for instance, it will check all the columns to see if there's an exact match for a table that has those specific columns and dump the data into that table, otherwise it will create a new table. There will also be a master table list with the checksum of each file to make sure there is not a duplicate when adding files into the db.

So

```
TABLE LIST
MD5 | File Name

FILE DATA
NAME | COLUMN 1 | COLUMN 2 | COLUMN 3
```

with the columns actually being the names of the columns, and the columns are not just limited to 3.

I've also looked into an EAV schema and considered NoSQL solutions but I'm not sure if those are the best options. There will be hundreds of thousands of files and a healthy amount of joins/queries to consider.

I could maybe use Postgres's hstore, but that only maps string:string. I was thinking mapping column-name: [array of values] for all the rows under that column in the data, is there another way to do this? Would using postgres's array be suitable?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? In Postgres you could use the (very efficient) key/value type `hstore`

Comment: And your joins will be highly dynamic - on any columns, having same (similar) name? Just curious :)

Comment: DBSM could be any at the moment, will look into hstore.
Yes, the joins will be pretty dynamic as such.

Comment: I'm not sure how hstores could work, arrays may work but it can get complicated since postgres arrays must be rectangular which can get tricky with malformed data